# How to save object changes to its XAML?

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, xaml

For example, in a WPF or Silverlight app I have:

```
<Rectangle Height="100" Width="200" Name="rectangle1" Stroke="Black" />
```

then in code I change its properties to:

```
rectangle1.Height = 50;
rectangle1.Width = 50;
```

**How could I save these changes to the object's XAML?** 
Like this:

```
<Rectangle Height="50" Width="50" Name="rectangle1" Stroke="Black" />
```

Comment: Do you want these changes to be done in design-time or during run-time?

Comment: In fact, I need to have a custom XAML design surface inside my application for granting users the possibility to edit my user controls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you'd like to output the XAML of your rectangle after changing the properties you specified, then you might want to checkout the `XamlWriter` class. There's a method called `Save` that will return a string containing the XAML equivalent of the object passed in.

[Check it out here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms590450.aspx). Hope this helps!

Comment: This is good for WPF. For Silverlight, there is no native XamlWriter, but David Poll posted on his blog a pretty good XAML serializer (even works on Windows Phone with further restrictions).  You can find that here : http://www.davidpoll.com/2010/07/25/to-xaml-with-love-an-experiment-with-xaml-serialization-in-silverlight/

Comment: Didn't know about that limitation (I'm primarily a WPF guy) - thanks for pointing that out! +1

Comment: Thanks! Useful, +1. Though this approach has some limitations: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754193.aspx